# Is this a valid way to speed up kFold cross validations for deep neural network training?

Tags: deep-learning

In the context of convolutional neural network training, I need to do a 10-fold cross validations of my training set.  Training just 1 of the 10 fold takes at least one hour on my GPU which means total time for training all 10 folds independently would take at least 10 hours!  To speed up training, will my kFold result be valid if I load and tune the trained weights from the fully trained model from the first fold (fold1) for each of the rest of the KFold models (fold2, fold3... fold10)?  Is there any side effect?

Comment: 10 hours is not much time in Deep Learning, you don't need to accelerate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That won't be doing any cross-validation.

The point of retraining the net is to ensure that it's trained on a different subset of your data, and for every full training, it keeps aside a set of validation data that it has never seen. If you reload your weights from a previous training instance, you're going to be validating against data your network has already seen, and your cross-validation score will be inflated.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense.